# Perpetual tasks in Celery?

Tags: python, django, multithreading, image, celery

I'm building a django app where I use a camera to capture images, analyze them, store metadata and results of the analysis in a database, and finally present the data to users.

I'm considering using Celery to handle to background process of capturing images and then processing them:

```py
app = Celery('myapp')

@app.task
def capture_and_process_images(camera):
    while True:
        image = camera.get_image()
        process_image(image)
        sleep(5000)

@app.task
def process_image(image):
    # do some calculations
    # django orm calls
    # etc...
```

The first task will run perpetually, while the second should take ~20 seconds, so there will be multiple images being processed at once.

I haven't found any examples online of using Celery in this way, so I'm not sure if this is bad practice or not.

Can/should Celery be used to handle perpetually running tasks?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Running perpetual tasks in Celery is done in practise. Take a look at [daemonization](https://celery.readthedocs.io/en/latest/userguide/daemonizing.html#daemonization), which essentially runs a permanent task without user interaction, so I wouldn't say there is anything wrong with running it permanently in your case.

Answer (score 0):

Having celery task running infinitely is not seems like a good idea to me.
If you are going to capture images at some intervals I would suggest you to use some cron-like script getting an image every 5 seconds and launching celery task to process it.
 Note also that it is a best practice to avoid synchronous subtasks in celery, see [docs](https://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/userguide/tasks.html#avoid-launching-synchronous-subtasks) for more details.

Comment: Ok thanks for the tip. I will just change the synchronous task to be asynchronous.